# optimizar el bucle para combinar elementos de una lista usando lapply o sapply en R

Tags: r, apply

Tengo como ejemplo la siguiente lista:

```
>lista 
[[1]]
      row col   
[1, ]   4 453
[2, ]   5 453

[[2]]
     row col
[1, ] 26 264
[2, ] 26 265
[3, ] 26 266
[4, ] 27 265
[5, ] 27 266

[[3]]
     row col
[1,]  35 364
[1,]  35 365
[2,]  35 366
```

el objetivo es, combinar los elementos de la lista, de la forma: lista[[1]] con lista[[2]], lista[[1]] con lista[[3]] sucesivamente (tengo una lista del orden de cinco mil elementos o más).

El resultado esperado es:

```
[[1]]
      row col   
[1, ]   4 453
[2, ]   5 453
[3, ]  26 264
[4, ]  26 265
[5, ]  26 266
[6, ]  27 265
[7, ]  27 266

[[2]]
     row col    
[1, ]  4 453
[2, ]  5 453
[3, ] 35 364
[4, ] 35 365
[5, ] 35 366
.
.
.
```

Entonces, tengo la siguiente función que realiza el trabajo, pero, como la cantidad de elementos de la lista es muy grande, este proceso tarda mucho tiempo.

```
rows_bind <- function(all_GG){
  nn_GG <- length(all_GG)
  lista_analizar <- list()
  cont <- 1
  repeat {
    lista_analizar[[cont]] <- rbind(all_GG[[1]], all_GG[[cont+1]])
    cont = cont + 1
    if (cont == nn_GG){
      break
    }
  }
  return(lista_analizar)
}
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿como puedo optimizar la función creada? para usarlo dentro de una función como **lapply** o **sapply**. O mejor aún usar **parSapply()** o **parLapply()**

Comment: comentar que la respuesta se encuentra en el siguiente link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64422577/2857542

Comment: Si tienes la solución a tu problema, responde la pregunta con una explicación y la solución.

Answer (score 1):

Esta pregunta fu respondida en el siguiente [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/64422577/2857542) empleando la función lapply:

para el primer caso se considera toda la lista, excluyendo el primer elemento con el signo negativo del índice (**lista[-1]**) y usando la función **rbind** para combinar por filas el primer elemento de la lista (**lista[1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/64422577/2857542)**) con los elementos restantes de la lista.

```
lapply(lista[-1], function(x) rbind(lista[[1]], x))
```

la otra opción es, generar una secuencia de números desde el dos hasta la longitud total de la lista y se usa la función **do.call** para combinar cada elemento.

```
lapply(seq(2,length(lista)), function(i) do.call(rbind, c(lista[1], lista[i])))
```

Ambos casos funcionan correctamente.